# Supply voltage of LM741 with Virtual Ground

Tags: power-supply, batteries, operational-amplifier, ground

I'm looking for a way to feed LM741 with a battery.
I found this example that uses the TLE2425 to create a virtual ground of 2.5V (in the original example was used opamp TLC272):

[image]

I simulated this circuit in Proteus and worked perfectly. But I do not understand how this works, because the voltage supply of LM741 is ± 5V to ± 22V, and this circuit feeding the LM741 with + 2.5v (+ Vcc) and -2.5V (-Vcc).

Answer (score 2):

Almost certainly the Proteus model for the 741 does not correspond exactly to the real thing. Particularly, it does not model the schematic of the IC. Rather, it uses a set of idealized components which have values (gain, frequency response, bias and offset currents, etc) chosen to correspond to the published data sheets. As a result, it works just fine as long as you operate within the published limits, but does not accurately reflect what happens when you operate outside those limits.